# Sudden decrease in daily user installs after update

Tags: android, statistics, metrics, google-play-console

I have an application in play store. I have pushed a new version on 09-May-2019
After I pushed the update on play store, the rest of the month starting 9th may, avg user installs have dropped to 70/ day and uninstalls are still at 175/ day approx

One thing amaze me is after 9th May there is a huge difference between install events and daily user installs. Following is the link to metrics for month of May

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-CPJQDlRNwrwAG-Dp3a7V2022Gmw-VGmPUaa2R9EPc/edit?usp=sharing`

Comment: May you have change the configuration of your analytics tool ? Like changing the identifier without purpose ?

Comment: Did you change the target API version?  Your app may work on fewer devices with the new version, and so, less chance of getting an install.

Comment: It may not be related to your update at all. I always see a decrease in my installs around this time of year, as my user base consists largely of students. May - Jun, students are focusing on exams, finishing up school. Then there's summer vacation, which can also impact installs. Maybe your situation is similar? Do you have data from previous years that you could compare to?